# Why isn't there a "share" link/button for articles in the Help Center?

Tags: feature-request, help-center

Visiting https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example I saw that there is not share button.

For regular posts (questions and answers) there is one.

Why not something similar for help center articles?

Comment: The purpose of the share button on questions and answers is to copy a specially formatted URL that you can use in other websites.  The special URL contains your user id for tracking purposes so people can get credit for specific badges (like [Announcer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer)).  There's no badges for sharing help center pages.  So what would you want to see from such a button?

Comment: "Copy Link (to clipboard)"? So for help center answers are no sub-elements, so no specific link?

Comment: Note that there are various shortcuts for putting links in comments: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting Some of those shortcuts also work in the chat rooms.

Comment: @U.Windl yes copy to clipboard.  And there is nothing specific to sharing that you can'y just copy the URL and paste it somewhere.

Comment: @U.Windl i think you are asking the wrong question - equating the "Share" functionality on questions and answers with what you want.  I assume you are asking for a way to link to specific sub-topics within the help center articles so you can point a user to a specific section

Comment: @PM2Ring I think those types of fragment identifiers are the exception rather than the rule. Are there any other help pages that you can use them on besides editing help? I wonder because there have been a number of feature requests asking for anchors for such things in the past...

Answer (score 15):

Here's a thought.  Why aren't we surfacing the Help Center articles on the front page, instead of hiding them behind an obscure button?

There are several ways to do this, but the most straightforward (and probably most effective) way is to include the most important ones (particularly the "How to Ask," "What to Ask" and MCVE articles) in the menu strip on the left hand side of the page.

Answer (score 5):

You can get badges for using the share button on posts, but nothing like that exists for anything that isn’t a question or answer—including the Help Center.

(It wouldn’t be such a bad idea to have a badge for enough people clicking on your links to the Help Center, actually. The more people that read that, the better.)

I’m not entirely convinced that adding a share button would make more people share Help Center articles, because anyone who wants to can just copy the url from the address bar. Having the ability to link to anchors would definitely be good though.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to find the shortcut links to the common help center pages, this would be an awesome feature to assist those new to the review queues who haven't yet memorised the short cuts.
So **as well as the standard share link** it would be better if there was also a quick summary usage guidance for those articles that have a shortcut link (and display the shortcut).

> Too much of how SO (and SE) works under the hood is not documented in a way as to encourage us plebians to get involved, the help articles surely should be there to assist the reviewers as much as they are there to assist those who are posting questions.